# Play Framework AJAX returns Object at badRequest()

Tags: java, ajax, playframework, return-type, bad-request

I know the badRequest() in play framework may result in rerendering a page like,

`badRequest(views.html.admin())`,

but I would like to return a String, in my case a SQLException.

> (SQLException e)

If I `return ok(e.toString())` instead of `return badRequest(e.toString())`it works, I think the return type of badRequest may be the problem. If I alert the data I get from the ajax call, I get for bad request [Object][object].

Is it even possible to return a String at badRequest() in java play framework?

My Javascript code is this :)

```
$("#deleteBuildingConfirm").click(function(q){
                       $('#confirmDelete').modal('hide');

                       $.ajax({
                        type : 'POST',
                        url : '@routes.Admin.deleteBuilding()',
                        data : {
                            id: idOfBuild, name: nameOfBuild
                        },
                        success : function(data) {

                            alert(data);
                         /** Wenn ein gebäude.. */

                        },
                         error : function(err) {

                            alert(err);             
                            }

                        });

                            return true;
                });
```

at `alert(err)` I always end up getting [Object][Object], when I trigger an SQLException.

This is my Java function:

```
public static Result deleteBuilding(){

        final Map<String, String[]> values = request().body().asFormUrlEncoded();
        final Long idToDelete = Long.parseLong(values.get("id")[0]);

        final String nameToDelete = values.get("name")[0];

        String message="Deleted on server, row with id: "+idToDelete+"\n "
                +"Building with name: "
                +nameToDelete+" has been deleted.";

        try {
            Building.delete(idToDelete);
            return ok(message);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            final String badMessage = e.toString();

            return badRequest(badMessage);
        }

    }
```

Thanks in advance :), this is really bothering me!
Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with `badRequest("Some String")` you can use it to return a string, or even any object accepted by Ok().

I think that the bad part lays on your Javascript code that trigger the ajax call, can you post it here it'll be useful.

When jQuery calls the erro call back he gives it an object with all the info needed to handle the error that hapened, if you're interested in the content of the request just change the code  to look like this:

```
$("#deleteBuildingConfirm").click(function(q){
                       $('#confirmDelete').modal('hide');

                       $.ajax({
                        type : 'POST',
                        url : '@routes.Admin.deleteBuilding()',
                        data : {
                            id: idOfBuild, name: nameOfBuild
                        },
                        success : function(data) {

                            alert(data);
                         /** Wenn ein gebäude.. */

                        },
                         error : function(err) {
                            // use err.responseText instead of err
                            alert(err.responseText);            
                            }

                        });

                            return true;
                });
```